# ExtnJS-“Element is not clickable at point” error

Tags: extjs, selenium-webdriver

When trying to click a button on `ExtnJs` appl I receive the error following error:

> org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Element is not clickable at
>   point (x, y). Other element would receive the click:  `<div id=" ">..</div>`

On clicking a button,page will be loaded with a new contents.

code:

```
driver.findElement(by.xpath("//a[@id='tabNameAtnBtn']")).click();
```

or

```
driver.findElement(by.xpath("//a/span/span/span[contains(text(),'Name')]")).click();
```

or

```
action.moveToElement(driver.findElement(by.xpath("//a[@id='tabNameAtnBtn']"))).click().perform();
```

`Click` operation is not happening, but the object is getting identified. and then fails with displaying the error message.

Please let me how to resolve this issue.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If unfortunately `.click()` does not work due to overlay of other element, you should try using `JavascriptExecutor` as below :-

```
WebElement el = driver.findElement(By.id("tabNameAtnBtn"));

((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click()", el);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,30);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("")));
```